# How to catch null pointer exception in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have got this piece of code :

```
var graphPoints:[Int] = DBController().dosmth()
```

And this calls a method which is supposed to return an array of `Int`. But how can I handle the situation when the values passed are not `Int`? At the moment it just throws this

`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

and I want to catch like so :

```
do{
    var graphPoints:[Int] = DBController().dosmth()
}
catch{ }
```

But this throws errors. Would be grateful if someone could point out what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Please download the Swift books for the iBook store. This is basic functionality of the Swift language and you _absolutely_ need to learn this.

Comment: And you are not getting a null pointer exception. You are getting an optional value which is nil, and if you unwrap it your app _will_ crash. That is intentional. Use if...let (check the Swift books) to access the data carefully.

Answer (score 6):

First, you can't catch this. It's a programming error. Programming errors indicate that the system is in an unknown state and are unrecoverable. If this is happening, you have a bug, and you must fix the bug.

This is not a "null pointer exception." There is no such thing in Swift. This error indicates that you're almost certainly using `!` somewhere that you should not be. `!` means "I absolutely know that this is going to work, and if I'm wrong, crash the program." You were wrong, and it crashed the program. That's not an exception.

Look into the code and find the place that you're using `!` incorrectly. "Incorrectly" means anywhere that you cannot prove, just by looking at the code in front of you, that it can *never* fail (and if it does anyway, you want to crash). If you mean "it *should* never fail," then you mean to use `?`, not `!`. Even better, whenever possible, rework the code so it actually *can* never fail. That's usually better than any kind of optional (whether explicit or implicitly unwrapped).

Comment: Sorry but no.  You should be able to catch this type of Exception.  Any modern language (.NET, Java) can and for good reason.  The state of the program will become known as the Exception is handled so that argument does not make sense.

For example if you are constructing a booking - catch the exception, things failed so the final object is null. null can then be passed back and nothing has to or should crash.

Comment: The behavior you describe is absolutely available in Swift by several mechanisms (`if-let`, `guard-let`, `map`, `flatMap`, `??`, `switch`, all highly supported and encouraged, often with syntactic sugar to make them very first-class). Using `!` means you explicitly do not want that behavior and and requesting a crash if there is a `nil`. This is not an exception. It is, intentionally, a fatal error and will crash because that's what `!` requests. If you don't want a crash here, then don't request one. `!` was not chosen by accident. It comes from the unix tradition where it's pronounced "bang"

Comment: if-let etc. is nothing like the Exception handling present in .NET or Java.  You can effectively catch the NSException or NullException then perform other actions if you were try - catching it

Comment: Sorry - an Exception is exactly the same as the fatal error.  After all does anyone actually want the program to crash?  No one requests a crash... Swift should have first class handling to actually capture those messages.

Comment: it is a bit short to say "Swift does it wrong because it works differently in other languages". Optionals are first-class citizens in Swift and there are a lot of mechanisms built around them. If the programmer defines an optional, does not ensure it is initialised (Swift network interaction always offers support for exception handling, i.e. JSON decoding errors or video streams) and then explicitly says "run this anyway", you might get a crash.

In the above example, you could as mentioned put a guard around it to unwrap or call "DBController()?.dosmth()".

Answer (score 4):

the method `dosmth()` should return `[Int]?` meaning it can return `nil`, then when using the `graphPoints` you would either if let unwrap like

```
if let graphPoints = graphPoints {
    use_graphPoints
}
```

or optional nil coalescing such as

```
grpahPoints?.count ?? 0
```

Alternatively you can set the `func dosmth()` as `throws` via

```
func dosmth() throws {

}
```

then when calling it

```
do {
    graphPoints:[Int] = try DBController().dosmth() 
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

more can be found here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap an optional value to make your code safe.

```
var graphPoints = [Int]()
if let array = DBController().dosmth() {
    graphPoints = array
}
```